# How to say ''Mathematics is the most beautiful and powerful creation of human spirit" in Japanese?

Tags: grammar

My attempt is as follows:

> 数{すう}学{がく}が一[番]{ばん}で美{うつく}しくて強{きょう}力{りょく}な人{にん}間{げん}の精{せい}神{しん}の創{そう}造{ぞう}です。

Is it correct?

Comment: Among many things: 創造 usually stands for "creating" creation but not "created" creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use as much of what you used as possible, just **drop the 「で」** and you will have at least a grammatical sentence.  You **cannot** say 「一番**で** + adjective」 to mean "most (adjective)" or "(adjective)est".

The next step would be to replace the conversational 「一番」 by the more formal「[最]{もっと}も」.

Then, I would seriously think about the validity of the 「が」 in 「数学が」.  Having been here so long, I know 「が」 is Japanese-learners' favorite subject marker.  (They often use it even when it should ***not*** be used at all.)  More context is needed to choose between 「は」 and 「が」 here.  Generally speaking, one needs a very good reason to use 「が」.

Answer (score 2):

It would be more natural:

> 数学は人間の精神による創造の中で、最も美しくそして強力なものです。

Although it may depend on the context, in this case, the original passage means, I suppose, that:

> Mathematics is one of the most beautiful and powerful creations that human spirit has ever created.

If so, at least, it would be better to say:

> 数学は

rather than

> 数学が.

Because **数学が** implies **only** or **emphasizing**, so it is going to be **Only Mathematics is** as if **数学だけが** or **It is Mathematics that ...**.
On the other hand, **数学は** does not mention others or means implicitly **at least**.

For example, to say **I study Japanese.**

> **私が**日本語を勉強します。

This sentence is more natural when there must be only one person to study Japanese in a group or class.

> **私は**日本語を勉強します。

This means that I do not know if other people do, but I do.
Or

> **私は**日本語を勉強しています。

This is more like **I study Japanese everyday.**

Answer (score 0):

I would say "人間(の)精神が精神が想像した最も美しく強力なものは数学である。", or "数学は人間(の)精神が想像した最も美しく、強力なものである。"